# Using QUERY command with dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I have a column in Sheet1 that contains dates in format DD/MM/YYYY, like this:

```
12/10/2015
28/09/2015
28/09/2015
28/09/2015
28/09/2015
28/09/2015
28/09/2015
26/10/2015
26/10/2015
26/10/2015
26/10/2015
12/10/2015
12/10/2015
12/10/2015
```

And I'm trying to select with a QUERY all the entries that are less than 15/10/2015. I know there are other methods but I need to use SQL syntax (this is a simplified version of the big formula and I need SQL to make the other bits work).

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("BLABLABLA", "Sheet1!A2:A"),"SELECT * WHERE Col1 <= '15/10/2015'")
```

But the query completes with an empty response. I even tried to use the MM-DD-YYYY format in the QUERY or just "2016"—still an empty response.

My spreadsheet’s locale is UK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
WHERE Col1 <= '15/10/2015'
```

with

```
WHERE Col1 <= date '2015-10-15'
```

That is, you need to provide date in [ISO format](https://xkcd.com/1179/) and precede it with the keyword `date` so that it is parsed accordingly.

Comment: Is there a way to sort the output? I tried adding ORDER BY Col1, but it acts weird. I think I need again to specify that they're dates?

Comment: Order by Col1 works fine for me. Can you give an example of input and output, preferably as another question?